# Can I still download the 0.3.1 iso anywhere?

Tags: system-installation, boot, uefi

Well, still working on the problem of installing elementary on a Bay Trail machine (32-bit bootloader, 64-bit processor). Unfortunately 0.3.2 doesn't support 32-bit UEFI any more, so I'd like to try with 0.3.1. Is the 0.3.1 ISO still available anywhere?

(Barring that, I'll probably just use Debian with the Pantheon DE...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0.3.1 doesn't support 32bit UEFI either. There is an open ticket for supporting 32bit UEFI in the future [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1519733)

Answer (score 0):

you may try this torrent

https://kat.cr/elementary-os-0-3-1-64-bit-t11632101.html 
or this https://kat.cr/elementary-os-freya-32bit-t10490137.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://sturmflut.github.io/linux/ubuntu/2015/02/04/installing-ubuntu-on-baytrail-tablets-version-2/) is how to make bootable installation media to bay trail devices.

> Modifying the installation medium to boot on 32-bit UEFI
>
> Yes, some genius came up with the idea to put a 32-bit UEFI on a 64-bit device. The Linux kernel shipped with Ubuntu 14.10 supports mixed-mode, so kernel-wise it is no longer a problem. But the Ubuntu 14.10 (Vivid Vervid) ISO does not contain a 32-bit bootloader. Luckily this can be easily fixed.
>
> Get a bootia32.efi file, I used this one from John Wells.
>      Copy the file into the EFI/BOOT/ folder on the boot medium.